# Как передать результат работы функции print в переменную?

Tags: python

Имеется вот такой код

```
from random import randint

rrn = [randint(0,9) for i in range(12)]
print('',*rrn, sep='3')
```

на выходе получается  такое значение 383434313930353137303532
как его заслать в пременную ?

Comment: var = "3".join([randint(0,9) for i in range(12)])

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from random import randint

rrn = [str(randint(0,9)+30) for i in range(12)]
var = "".join(rrn)
```

или сразу генерировать от 30 до 39

```
rrn = [str(randint(30,39)) for i in range(12)]
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное!